# CORS Error Connecting to AspNet.SignalR Hub from Angular8

Tags: signalr, angular8, signalr-hub

I am attempting to create a service in Angular8 to connect to my SignalR Hub running in the Visual Studio debugger. My Angular8 is hosted on a different domain name, so I added the CorsOptions.AllowAll code to the SignalR startup.cs as suggested in several posts on StackOverflow.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration { };
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now when my Angular8 service attempts to connect to the server, the Preflight throws a CORS Error.

[image: CORS Error on connection.start()]

Here is the snippet from my Service to communicate with SignalR. Note that in this snippet I import 'signalr', but I get the same error when I try to use '@aspnet/signalr' or '@microsoft/signalr'.

```
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from 'signalr';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ChatMessage } from './chat.model';

@Injectable()
export class ChatService implements OnInit {

    private connection: signalR.HubConnection;
    connectionEstablished = new Subject<Boolean>();
    receiverSubscription = new Subject<String>();
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
 
  connect() {
    if (!this.connection) {
      this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('https://localhost:44323/signalr')
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
      .build();
 
      this.connection.start().then(() => {
        console.log('Hub connection started');
        this.connectionEstablished.next(true);
      }).catch(err => console.log(err));
 
      this.connection.on('SendChat', (chatMessage) => {
        console.log('Received', chatMessage);
        this.receiverSubscription.next(chatMessage);
      });
     }
```

Oddly, I do NOT get this error when I test using the jQuery client hosted on the different domain name. The one difference that jumps out at me is that jQuery adds some params to the negotiate url that Angular does not:

[image: Successful call to 'negotiate' from jQuery]

Can anyone help me with what I am missing, or how I can debug this issue?